# Alignment issue when i was covert http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to update secure server on my HTTP domain to HTTPS domain and also from NON-WWW to WWW through .htaccess.

1. http://assignmentbox.co.uk/ → https://assignmentbox.co.uk/
2. https://assignmentbox.co.uk/ → https://www.assignmentbox.co.uk/

and coded

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^assignmentbox\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.assignmentbox.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: when i used redirection through htacces its showing error 500 that's why i redirect thorough redirection code 301 ...